# SQL Inner Join not exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following categories (Many to many relations):

```
+ post

post_tag

+ tag

post_category

+ category
```

How can i create SQL query to check which tags are in a post without category?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Can you show us your table structures??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select  distinct pt.tagname
from    post_tag pt
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    post_category pc
        where   pc.post_id = pt.post_id
        )
```